# React create a qr code component transform it into a base64 image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, qr-code

Within a table (`react-data-table-component`), I have elements, one of these elements, the text must be converted into qr code.

I'm trying various modules (`qrcode.react, react-google-qrcode, etc.`).

The problem is that they are components so the only way to use them as documentation is:

```
<qrCode value = "text" />
```

The problem that I need to convert the QR code into an image,
because then I have to put it in a pdf that I have to generate.

So I thought I encoded the image in base64.

But I'm not able to find a way to do it.

You know how to give me advice.

Comment: Instead of a component, you can use a module like [qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode), generate a data URL image that you can use as a `src` for an image element in React or a base64 encoded image in your PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode module to convert your dataset into an image as QR code.

```
    QRCode.toDataURL(<YOUR_DATASET>, {type: "png"})
    .then(img => {
       // Then you can do whatever you want with this img
    })
```

Comment: is there another way?